# Issues with validation using carrierwave gem in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, validation, carrierwave

Hey so this is really bugging me. I've implemented Carrierwave into my app with a simple image upload. Im trying to validate the image to be the correct filetype and I'm getting a few strange results. Heres the relevant code:

```
class Art < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :collection
attr_accessible :image, :collection_id, :remote_image_url
mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
validates_integrity_of :image
validates_presence_of :image
validates_processing_of :image
end
```

```
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

storage :file

def store_dir
  "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
end

def extension_white_list
  %w(jpg jpeg gif)
end
```

```
class ArtsController < ApplicationController

def new
  @art = Art.new(:collection_id => params[:collection_id])
end

def edit
  @art = Art.find(params[:id])
end

def create
  @art = Art.new(params[:art])
    if @art.save
      flash[:notice] = "Successfully created art."
  redirect_to @art.collection
    else
      flash[:error] = @art.errors
  render :action => :new
   end
end

def update
  @art = Art.find(params[:id])

    if @art.update_attributes(params[:art])
  flash[:notice] = "Successfully updated art."
  redirect_to @art.collection
    else
  flash[:error] = @art.errors
  render :action => :edit
  end
end

def destroy
  @art = Art.find(params[:id])
  @art.destroy
flash[:notice] = "Successfully destroyed art."
redirect_to @art.collection
  end
end
```

```
en:
  errors:
   messages:
     carrierwave_processing_error: "Cannot resize image."
     carrierwave_integrity_error: "Not an image."
     carrierwave_download_error: "Couldn't download image."
     extension_white_list_error: "NOT ALLOWED"
     extension_black_list_error: "You are not allowed to upload %{extension} files, 
     prohibited types: %{prohibited_types}"
```

So when i create a new piece of art with a png file format an error will occur that the image cannot be blank. I understand this is the validates_presence_of being trigger but i am supplying it with something just not the correct format. If i remove the validates_presence_of non correct file formats won't display but will still be created. I also assed the i18n error messages to my en.yml file. I'm somewhat new to rails so i assume there is an issue in my controller with creating each piece of art but im not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: And uploading a jpg works as expected, right? Does it show the same behavior on update? What happens if you try it at the rails console?

Comment: Yes uploading a jpg works as expected and updating to a different picture of a white listed extension works.